# How to decompile and recompile dex files

Tags: android, dex

So I decompiled a `.dex` file into a directory that has the following folders(inside a source folder with nothing else in it):

1. Org
2. Okhttp3
3. Defpackage
4. Bolts
5. Bitter
6. Android
7. Kotlin
8. Javax
9. Dagger
10. Androidx
11. Com

I wanted to edit some of the files from this and then recompile it but I don't know how I would be able to recompile the whole directory back into dex to recreate the APK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reverse engineering tools like [ApkTool](https://github.com/iBotPeaches/Apktool)

Comment: Would this require getting the original APK again since I've already decompiled the APK?

Comment: @user19926715 It is better to read the documentation of the tool, it is not very difficult to work with it